# Entity Framework DateTime update extremely slow

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, datetime, entity-framework-4

I have this situation currently with Entity Framework:

```
using (TestEntities dataContext = DataContext)
            {
                UserSession session = dataContext.UserSessions.FirstOrDefault(userSession => userSession.Id == SessionId);
                if (session != null)
                {
                    session.LastAvailableDate = DateTime.Now;
                    dataContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

This is all working perfect, except for the fact that it is terribly slow compared to what I expect (14 calls per second, tested with 100 iterations). When I update this record manually through this command:

```
dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String.Format("update UserSession set LastAvailableDate = '{0}' where Id = '{1}'", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"), SessionId));
```

I get 55 calls per second, which is more than fast enough. However, when I don't update the session.LastAvailableDate but I update an integer (e.g. session.UserId) or string with Entity Framework, I get 50 calls per second, which is also more than fast enough. Only the datetime field is terrible slow.

The difference of a factor 4 is unacceptable and I was wondering how I can improve this as I don't prefer using direct SQL when I can also use the Entity Framework.

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3.1 (also tried 4.1).

Comment: Try using the MiniProfiler (search in NuGet). It'll show you the SQL EF generates and the execution times, so you can pinpoint what the problem could be.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about it. I'll look into it.

Comment: If you figure out the problem, please take two minutes to write an answer to your own question here :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out, your sql command is only one query, while your EF command is two queries (getting the data, then saving it), so right there you can see a 2x difference.

Also, you may find you get better performance by querying by ID rather than ad-hoc query.  Assuming that SessionId is the primary key lookup.

```
UserSession session = dataContext.UserSessions.Find(SessionId);
```

Comment: I'm aware that EF is using two queries, but when I update another field of that session (for example: session.UserId instead of session.LastAvailableDate), I still get 50 calls per second, whereas when I update a DateTime field I have horrible performance. I'm aware of and already tried the Find method but it didn't improve the performance.